# Homoclinically related hyperbolic periodic points gives the same pesin homoclinic class up to null sets

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, hyperbolic-dynamics

In [*MINIMALITY AND STABLE BERNOULLINESS IN DIMENSION 3* by Nunez and Hertz](https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.04414v2), the first paragraph in the proof of Corollary 2.4 says the above statement follows by using a "$\lambda$-lemma". What exactly is this lemma? Or what is the idea behind this statement?

Comment: It says $\Gamma$-lemma, not $\lambda$-lemma.

Comment: @AlessandroDellaCorte Should it be obvious from that what the lemma is?

Comment: @Will Sawin  Not for me...

Comment: It should be $\lambda$-Lemma, the $\Gamma$ is a typo. This is also known as the inclination lemma and it states that given a hyperbolic periodic point p, any disc transverse to the stable manifold of p will "converge" to the unstable manifold in the C^1 topology for future iterates, you can find this at Palis-DeMelo book. This is also true for non-uniformly hyperbolic systems using Pesin theory, see Lemma 2.7 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.02240.pdf for example.